# How to avoid executing the method written in @AfterSuite if a single test is executed as 'TestNG Test' or using the 'Run' command provided by plugin

Tags: java, selenium, testng

BaseTest Class

```
public class BaseTest extends Base {
    LoginPage login;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Base.class);

    @BeforeMethod()
    public void setUp() throws IOException, IOException {
        logger.info("starting initialisation method from base class");
        initialisation();
        logger.info("completed initialisation method from base class");
        login = new LoginPage();
        logger.info("initialising login page and profile page object");
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        logger.info("starting tear down method");
        Base.getDriver().close();
        logger.info("ending tear down method");
    }
    @AfterSuite
    public void sendEmailWithExtentReport() throws IOException {
        logger.info("starting sendEmailWithExtentReport");
        Utilities.sendJavaMailAfterExecution();
        logger.info("ending sendEmailWithExtentReport");
        
}
```

LoginTest class

```
public class LoginTest extends BaseTest {
@Test(priority = 0,description = "Test case to verify login button is present or not")
    public void loginPageLoadingTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        logger.info("starting loginPageLoadingTest");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Assert.assertEquals(login.verifyLoginButton(), true);
        logger.info("ending loginPageLoadingTest");
    }
@Test(priority = 1, description = "Test case to verify login page title")
    public void loginPageTitleTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        logger.info("starting loginPageTitleTest");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Assert.assertEquals(login.getLoginPageTitle(), "Console");
        logger.info("ending loginPageTitleTest");
    }
}
```

testng-console.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.analyzer.MyTransformer" />
        <listener class-name="com.utilities.TestListener"></listener>
    </listeners>
    <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.ui.tests.BaseTest" />
            <class name="com.ui.tests.LoginTest" />
            <class name="com.ui.tests.FilterTest" /> -->
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I need to skip the method in @AfterSuite if i am only executing the single test case from multiple test cases in LoginTest class without using testng.xml file, so that I can verify each test case separately. Right now when individual test is executed the method in @AfterSuite is also getting executed. I want to execute the method in @AfterSuite only when test cases are executed using testng.xml file. How can i add a condition in @AfterSuite to achieve this. Also i am using this command '''mvn clean test -Dbrowsername=chrome''' from command prompt. My testng file name is testng-console.xml .The method in @AfterSuite should only get executed when using the tesng-console.xml. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your suite name for equality to `Default Suite`. Say you have `testng.xml` like:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
    <test name="MyTest" >
        <classes>
            <class name="click.webelement.Suites" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

where you define suite name explicitly. Then you can have the logic like this:

```java
package click.webelement;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Suites {

    @Test
    public void doTest(){
        System.out.println("Doing test..");
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void doingAfterSuite(ITestContext testContext){
        if(!testContext.getSuite().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Default Suite")){
            System.out.println("Doing after suite");
        }
    }

}
```

Since when you run a single test, `Default Suite` is created you can just test if default suite is set in test context.

**UPDATE:** Eclipse plugin sets default suite name as `Default suite` so that I changed `equals` to `EqualsIgnoreCase` to cover both Idea and Eclipse

Comment: Thanks for the reply . But this is not covering my requirement. I think my question did not went through as expected. So, I have updated my question. Can you please update your answer as per the updated question? Hope my question is clear now!

Comment: My answer exactly covers your case. It demonstrates that `System.out.println("Doing after suite");` is not called when you run test individually and executes when you run `testng.xml`

Comment: Do i need to change  suite name from "Default Suite" to "testng-console.xml" in my case right?

Comment: Show your `testng.xml` or `testng-console.xml` if you run that file

Comment: I have added my testng-console.xml file in question @Alexey R.

Comment: @cyrilgeorge153 You have `<suite name="Suite">` in your `.xml` file. So you should not change anything. When you run tests from your `.xml` file, your suite name is `Suite` hence this condition `!testContext.getSuite().getName().equals("Default Suite")` is `true` and that will execute the code inside `if`. When you run a single test from IDE suite name is set by default to `Default Suite`  hence the condition is `false` and the code wont run into `if` block.

Comment: I have made the changes like your answer but when i run testng-console.xml and run testcase from eclipse ide using run option of testng plugin , the if block is getting executed

Comment: I have one more testng.xml file whose name testng-console-parallel.xml . There also <suite name="Suite"> is given. Is that because of that it is not working?

Comment: `@AfterSuite
 public void sendEmailWithExtentReport(ITestContext testContext) throws IOException {
if(!testContext.getSuite().getName().equals("Default Suite"))
   {
        System.out.println("Doing after suite");
        logger.info("starting sendEmailWithExtentReport");
     Utilities.sendJavaMailAfterExecution();
     logger.info("ending sendEmailWithExtentReport");
        }
 }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239803/discussion-between-cyrilgeorge153-and-alexey-r).

Comment: @cyrilgeorge153 I have updated my answer. Eclipse plugin sets slightly different default suite name hence I added ignoring case to my logic.

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase did the trick! BRILLIANT